# custom user location with map kit

Tags: xcode4, location, mapkit

I found a lot of tutorials on how to set up an user location in the mapkit framework.
But the location is always in calfornia.

Is there any way to customize the location? for example setting it to a specific point on the map using longitude and altitude?

greetings

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do.  On the simulator, the user location is simulated (eg. on the Simulator menu, go to Debug|Location).  On a device, it will show the actual location.  You can't override the location of the built-in blue dot on the device.  You'll need to add your own annotation and specify the coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using the simulator. In Xcode when you're testing your app you can select a GPX file made of wpt items and it will send that data to the iOS simulator as if you are really at that location.

Click on the location indicator at the top of the debug panel (looks like an arrow, only visible while running your app in the simulator) and import a gpx file.

[image: Simulate Location button]

Here's a simple file for you to try out:

```
<gpx>           
        <wpt lat="-39.308983" lon="175.517223" />
        <wpt lat="-39.308217" lon="175.518553" />
</gpx>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Thats just what im looking for. Unfortunately it doesnt work with my project. I created a gpx file with the location i needed, but every time i add it to the debug panel my xcode crashes. Here the beginning of the errordetails: ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEFoundation/IDEFoundation-937/Framework/Classes/LocationSimulatio‌​n/IDELocationScenario.m:90 Details: (latitude) should not be nil. Object: <IDELocationScenario: 0x201cfeee0> Method: -_locationsFromReferencedGPXFileWithError: Thread: <NSThread: 0x200025720>{name = (null), num = 1} Any ideas?

Comment: Try it with the GPX file I quoted above. If that also fails then I can't help, you should file a bug report with apple. Xcode shouldn't crash. If it works ok then I think you've got a bung gpx file.